# Flexbox: keep elements left and right

Tags: html, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to get a list of buttons rendered horizontally. Each row consists of two buttons, a left and a right button. In some rows the left button is hidden (`display: none`), but the right button should still appear on the right-hand side of the row.

I'm using Bootstrap, but couldn't find a suitable style, so I came up with my own one. I am struggling with the problem that if the left button is hidden, the right one takes the position of the left on and appears at the far left. I've tried setting the `order: 0` (for the left button) and `order: 1` for the right button, but that doesn't make a difference.

```
.align-horizontal {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
```

html:

```
<tr>
  <td>

   <div class='align-horizontal'>
     <button>left</button>
     <button style='display: none'>right</button>
   </div>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
   <div class='align-horizontal'>
     <button>left</button>
     <button>right</button>
   </div>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
   <div class='align-horizontal'>
     <!-- this is where the layout breaks and the right button moves to the left -->
     <button style='display: none>left</button>
     <button>right</button>
   </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

How can I get the right button to always stay at the far right even if the left button is hidden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flexbox `justify-content:between` will only work if both elements are displayed. A workaround is to make the left button `visiblity:hidden` instead of  `display:none`...

```
<tr>
  <td>
   <div class='align-horizontal d-flex w-100 justify-content-between'>
     <button class="invisible">left</button>
     <button>right</button>
   </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

If you must use `display:none` another option is to use left auto-margins (`ml-auto`) on the `right` button to push it to the right.

```
<tr>
  <td>
   <div class='align-horizontal d-flex justify-content-between'>
     <button class="d-none">left</button>
     <button class="ml-auto">right</button>
   </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/JXxWPZl6tK